# PHP form either one of two text fields required

Tags: php, forms, submit, required

I realize there are similar threads regarding .asp pages, however I am using an html form with php involved with the submit action leading into a survey.

The client I am developing for would like either one of the text fields to be filled out, while neither one is hard required one of the two must be filled out.  It can be either of the two, however both cannot be left blank.

I would prefer to not use jquery, however if this is necessary I will learn how.  I am brand new to all of this and just creating the form and connecting it to the database took a whole lot of learning lol.

Thank you for any help, below I have posted the HTML form, and the php script it is linked to.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="varchar" name="name" />
<span style="color: #F00">or</span> Email:
<input type="varchar" name="email" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The PHP 'insert.php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","gobagtoo_1","1");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("gobagtoo_1", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO name_email (name, email)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else 
$url = 'tool.html';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

M

Comment: Make sure to escape name/email to prevent injection.

Comment: Varchar isn't a valid type of form input element.

Comment: Submitted an edit for peer review removing his DB hostname and system specific information

Comment: Sure it is. It just doesn't have any special behaviour attached to it so it behaves like a `"text"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should accomplish this both on the client side (where you see the form) with javascript and on the server side (the PHP after you submit the form).

On the client side:
1. Add the function to the page, validateForm.
2. Add id attributes to your name and email elements.
3. Add an onsubmit element to your form tag.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript">
    function validateForm(){
        var value1 = document.getElementById('nameId').value;
        var value2 = document.getElementById('emailId').value;
        if( value1 != "" || value2 != "" ) 
        {
            return true;    
        }
        alert("You must enter a value");
        return false;
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="nameId" /> 
    <span style="color: #F00">or</span> Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="emailId" />
    <input type="submit" /> 
    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

On the PHP side:

```
    <?PHP

    function makeSafeish( $value ){
        return mysql_escape_real_string( $value );
        // If you put this in a function, you can do more w/ it. I don't use this as is but don't want to be judged by the community here for my bad use :P
    }

    if( strlen( $_POST['name'] ) > 0 && strlen( $_POST['email'] ) > 0 ){
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","******","******"); 
        if (!$con) { 
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
        }  
        mysql_select_db("*****", $con); 
        $sql="INSERT INTO name_email (name, email) VALUES ('".makeSafeish( $_POST["name"] )."','".makeSafeish( $_POST["email"] )."')"; 
        if ( ! mysql_query( $sql, $con ) ) { 
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
        } else  {
            $url = 'tool.html'; 
        }

        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';    
        mysql_close($con); // you're not gonna get here because of the above line.
    }else{
        echo 'You must enter either an email or name.";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Good answer. A few notes, you should keep a consistent spacing convention, (either `}else{` or `} else {`), also, recommend using a different feature than `mysql_*`, as it is effectively deprecated. I suggest PDO.

Comment: Hi Truth, thanks for your comments. To the OP, I agree that you should use PDO; I don't use mysql_ either though that is how I learned first.  PDO will also help you prevent SQL injection.  Also, I was using his spacing which is different than the convention I normally use, so the discrepancy.  To OP, at a minium, I would tell you to always put a space on both side of ! if you use it.

Comment: @phpmeh  It is very close to working, it requires I enter at least one of the fields, however I  get the following error.   I greatly appreciate this help.

    Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1        in /home/gobagtoo/public_html/insert.php on line 24

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/gobagtoo/public_html/insert.php on line 24

Comment: Please do not use any naming convention or any mistakes that I have made, as I am using this to learn :)  You guys are WAY ahead of where I am at with this stuff.

So what I noticed was in thte line 'Echo 'You must enter either an email or name." that  there was a single quote and a double quote at the end I changed that and now the only error I get is .

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_real_string() in /home/gobagtoo/public_html/insert.php on line 4

Comment: Oops, I reversed the words: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
You should change it to mysql_real_escape_string instead of the escape_real

Comment: @phpmeh,

Ok, I'm not trying to be annoying on this one, and if I could figure it out myself I would but now whether I enter either only a name, or only an email I get the error page 'You must enter either an email or name.'  If I enter both I get to the page after which is the goal.

Comment: Hi Matt.  Not annoying.  Sorry I wrote bad code... The if line right now reads: "If the string length of the email post AND the string length of the name post are greater than 0, then do the following".  Instead, it should be OR.  Change the && to ||.

Comment: AWESOME, this is my first experience with this website and I can see it's going to become part of bag of tools from here on out.  

@phpmeh - THANKS!!  I promised this to a client thinking it would be easier to learn.  Now I have learned a lot, got it done on time and found a great place to learn.  Thank you very much.  Is there a way to give 'rep' points on here?  M

Comment: I edited the code to reflect the changes made to fix the errors.

Comment: @phpmeh -> Thank you for a great first stackoverflow experience!

Comment: @MattDouglas Glad it helped!  I don't know as much as most of the experts in this community, so it's always nice to be able to contribute.  :P